# Debugging Cursor object has no attribute _exit_ from ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, cursor, loop

I am trying to replace NULL values for -999 in a table inside a gdb. I know how to replace the value for individual fields, but get an error when looping through the complete table.

```
import arcpy
fc ="C:\gSSURGO.gdb\chorizon_va_1"
fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(fc)

with arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc, [fieldList]) as cursor:
 fRange = range(len(fieldList)) 
 for row in cursor:

     for index in fRange:
         if row[index] == None:
             row[index] = -999 
     cursor.updateRow(row)
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Runtime error : 'Cursor' object has no attribute '_exit_'
```

I found some examples using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor, but when I use that I get this error:

```
Runtime error <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: 'module' object has no attribute 'da'
```

I am using ArcMap 10.0.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.0

Comment: Just as an aside, I generally find None (NULL) is much more suited to representing absence than a value like -999. Although you haven't elaborated on your reasons, consider that NULL is far less ambiguous than a numerical value, especially if down the track someone other than you will be using the data. In some cases, -999 is s meaningful value in itself. Further, it is easier for someone to filter out None values than to have to guess what value represents NULL and then filter them.

Comment: I need to export the data and do some further processing. When I export is as dbf, NULL is converted to zero .. So I use -999 to be able to distinguish zero from NULL values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated to ArcMap 10.2.

This worked for all types of fields:

```
import arcpy

fc ="C:\gSSURGO_test.gdb\chor_comp_zone1"
fieldObs = arcpy.ListFields (fc)
fieldNames = [] 

for field in fieldObs:
    fieldNames.append(field.name)  

fieldCount = len(fieldNames)

curU = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fieldNames)
for row in curU:
         rowU = row 
         for field in range(fieldCount):
                      if rowU[field] == None:
                         rowU[field] = -999
         curU.updateRow(rowU)
```

Answer (score 4):

ArcPy did not have a Data Access module until ArcGIS 10.1. This will explain your second error message.

The only way to specify fields in ArcPy cursors prior to that was by using their names rather than an index.

Comment: And arcpy.*Cursors do not support the `with` statement.

Comment: Additionally, you need be careful while doing this row update, since you have different field types as looping the fields (i.e., fieldList) and need to elaborate "-999" differently for some.